# Bootstrap 5 - checkboxes are not lining up with labels

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying out Bootstrap 5 and am having difficulty lining up my checkboxes and their labels. The code is:

```
<div class="row col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
    <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="state"><b>Branch</b></label>
    <div class="form-check">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>ACT</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="act" name="state[]">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="nsw" name="state[]">NSW</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="nt" name="state[]">
            <label>NT</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="qld" name="state[]">QLD</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="pull-left"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="sa" name="state[]">SA</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="tas" name="state[]">TAS</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="vic" name="state[]">VIC</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="wa" name="state[]">WA</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see I have tried three variations.

From the edited first answer - this results:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="state"><b>Branch</b></label>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="act" name="state[]">
                <label class="form-check-label">ACT</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="nsw" name="state[]">
                <label class="form-check-label">NSW</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gives:

[image]

I have tried adding:

```
.big-checkbox {
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px;
}
```

This just increases the height of the check (it is still long).

Answer (score 1):

The "custom check" html composition is [changed in Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms). Now each [checkbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#checks) should look the follows (along with parent containers):

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-check">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="act" name="state[]" />
     <label class="form-check-label" for="act">ACT</label>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 5 Check CodePen](https://codepen.io/p_mike/pen/rNyzxaY)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this gives long checkboxes. I have edited my question to show the result.

Comment: It appears that your row/col structure is incorrect. The "col" should be inside "row" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/, but not mixed. Updated my code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however, this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you post a complete page to a embed code snippet or even better fiddle/codepen?

Comment: I have posted https://codepen.io/p_mike/pen/rNyzxaY pen for your reference.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, the jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/Glyndwr/h2kav7bx/ I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Found the problem. Remove the css - input, textarea {
   width: 100% !important
  }

Comment: Great! Nevertheless, the suggested edits should be performed.

Comment: Yes Mikhail, thank you very much for your help I have implemented your changes.